Not Parsing Hindi When Converting HTML to Image in ASP.NET Core Web API
I am generating a card and downloading using api. One can enter a card number and card is generated and downloaded. But the card contains some hindi texts which is not rendering correctly in the downloaded image.
I am using CoreHtmlToImage package
Here is controller function:
[HttpPost("/card/download")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadCard([FromForm]string CardNumber)
{
    if (CardNumber == null) return BadRequest("Card Number cannot be empty");

    try
    {
        var card = await _repository.GetCard(CardNumber);
        if (card == null) return BadRequest("Card not found");

        var backImage = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Images/", "card-template.png");

        var htmlContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Static/card-template.html");

        htmlContent = htmlContent.Replace("{{BackgroundImage}}", backImage)
                        .Replace("{{Name}}", card.Name)
                        .Replace("{{NameInHindi}}", card.NameInHindi)
                        .Replace("{{DateOfBirth}}", card.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        var image = await GenerateImageAsync(htmlContent);

        return File(image, "image/png", $"Card_{card.CardNumber}.png");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

This is the image generation function
private async Task<byte[]> GenerateImageAsync(string htmlContent)
{
    var converter = new HtmlConverter();
    var bytes = converter.FromHtmlString(htmlContent, 700, ImageFormat.Png);
    return bytes;
}

This is card template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Card</title>
    <style></style>
</head>

<body class="card__body">
    <div class="main__container">
        <img class="img" src="{{BackgroundImage}}" alt="">
        <div class="main__wrapper">
            <div class="user__details">
                <p class="name__hindi">{{NameInHindi}}</p>
                <p class="name__english">{{Name}}</p>
                <p class="dob">जन्म तिथि / DOB : {{DateOfBirth}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>{{CardNumber}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

I did try to use some hindi fonts and link in the css part but it didn.t work. I also tried to download hindi font and installed in my system, but it also didn't work.

At first, I think adding <meta charset="UTF-8"> should solve the issue, but you already had it in your html content. Could you pls debug your code and check the html content for variable string htmlContent?

I had a test in my side with your codes, and at first I think this is becuase File.WriteAllText(text, htmlContent); doesn't set Encoding.UTF8 in the parameter, but it's provded I'm wrong.  But if I remove the <meta charset="UTF-8"> within the html string, the jpg file will display as other words instead of black square. I'm afraid the root cause is the wkhtmltoimage.exe doesn't support Hindi words. Because when I used Chinese words, it worked. https://i.sstatic.net/rD8pzdkZ.png
